# Titanium Documentation for Windows Phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have an application built with the Titanium SDK that runs fine on iOS and Android. Now that Windows Phone can be targeted using Appcelerator Studio, I tried to publish the app to this platform. It published and ran but the app looks horrible and behaves unexpected and clearly needs some work.

When I search through Appcelerator's documentation for the Titanium SDK, the properties and methods for say "Ti.UI.View" do not have the Windows supported logo next to them? How do I know what properties and methods of the various classes are supported / I can use? I will post an example link below. It is for Ti.UI.View

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-touchEnabled

Is there another source of documentation I am missing? Does anyone know if Appcelerator plan on updating their docs?

Answer (score 0):

If the property does not clarify anything supports all e.g: [BackgroundColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-backgroundColor), but if the property supported only some are shown as follows: e.g [BackgroundDisabledColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-backgroundDisabledColor) (Windows and Android)

I'm not sure if the documentation is up-to 100%

Documentation for windows:

1. [Windows Phone specific UI capabilities](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Windows)
2. [Windows UI Components and Conventions](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Windows_UI_Components_and_Conventions)